# Random pairs of different bits

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, binary, bit

I have the following problem. I have a number represented in binary representation. I need a way to randomly select two bits of them that are different (i.e. find a 1 and a 0). Besides this I run other operations on that number (reversing sequences, permute sequences,...) These are the approaches I already used:

- Keep track of all the ones and the zeros. When I create the binary representation of the binary number I store the places of the 0's and 1's. So that I can choose an index for one list and one index from the other one. I then have two different bits. To run my other operations I created those from an elementary swap operations which updates the indices of the 1's and 0's when manipulating. Therefore I have a third list that stores the list index for each bit. If a bit is 1 I know where to find in the list with all the indices of the ones (same goes for zeros).
- The method above yields some overhead when operations are done that do not require the bits to be different. So another way would be to create the lists whenever different bits are needed.

Does anyone have a better idea to do this? I need these operations to be really fast (I am working with popcount, clz, and other binary operations)

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly select two different bits"? If the two bits are always going to be different, that's not random: you will always get a 1 and a 0.

Comment: What are you going to want to do if the number if 00000000 or 11111111?

Comment: If you XOR the two numbers, 1 bits in the result will tell you where you have different bits in the two input values.  Take it from there as to what you want to do with that info.

Comment: @TomPage This case is caught and nothing will be done. I my application all my 0 is represented by the bitstring 0. And the case where all bits are one will not happen either (my function will return if this is the case)

Comment: @pjs That will not help me as I would have to find a random one in the result of the xor. This is exactly the problem. Already thought about xor before.

Comment: And are we looking for something random with each 0 or 1 being equally probable to be chosen or does it matter if some come up a bit more often than others?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I am interested in their indices not their values (they only have to be different). An example: Having 1000110101 I want to find the index of one of the bits that is equal to 1 and one of the ones that is equal to 0

Comment: @TomPage The bits should be chosen with equal probability.

Comment: When you say "I store the places of the 0's and 1's" that sounds as if you've got some kind of array structures going on. It might be more efficient to just store the number of 0s and 1s so that if there's 3 0s and 5 1s you can generate a random number between 1 and 3 and a random number between 1 and 5 to identify them

Comment: Or maybe I've got the wrong end of the stick entirely

Comment: That is also stored for some other pruposes (I got a highly specialized bitset class). In my application memory is no problem at all. Storing only the number would not be sufficient or not? That is exactly what my question aims at. Is there a way to solve the problem without having to keep track of all the bits. I guess there is no such solution.

Comment: Aha, I had missed that you were talking about the bits of a single number.  I thought you were talking about two numbers and wanted to identify the set of bits that were different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel as though I have enough information to assess the tradeoffs properly, but perhaps you'll find this idea useful. To find a random 1 in a word (find a 1 over multiple words by popcount and reservoir sampling; find a 0 by complementing), first test the popcount. If the popcount is high, then generate indexes uniformly at random and test them until a one is found. If the popcount is medium, then take bitwise ANDs with uniform random masks (but keep the original if the AND is zero) to reduce the popcount. When the popcount is low, use clz to compile the (small) list of candidates efficiently and then sample uniformly at random.

Comment: I feel like this is not faster than storing the positions of 1's and 0's but it sounds quite interesting. My bitstrings change dramatically due to the other operations so that I only have small integers (like 32/64bit) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might be a rather efficient algorithm to do what you are asking. You only iterate over each bit in the number once, and for each element, you have to generate a random number (not exactly sure how costly that is, but I believe there are some optimized CPU instructions for getting random numbers).

Idea is to iterate over all the bits, and with the right probability, update the index to the current index you are visiting.

Generic pseudocode for getting an element from a stream/array:

```
p = 1
e = null
for s in stream:
  with probability 1/p:
    replace e with s
  p++
return e
```

Java version:

```
int[] getIdx(int n){
    int oneIdx  = 0;
    int zeroIdx = 0;

    int ones = 1;
    int zeros = 1;

    // this loop depends on whether you want to select all the prepended zeros
    // in a 32/64 bit representation. Alter to your liking...

    for(int i = n, j = 0; i > 0; i = i >>> 1, j++){
      if((i & 1) == 1){ // current element is 1
        if(Math.random() < 1/(float)ones){
          oneIdx = j;
        }
        ones++;
      } else{ // element is 0
        if(Math.random() < 1/(float)zeros){
          zeroIdx = j;
        }
        zeros++;
      }
    }
    return new int[]{zeroIdx,oneIdx};
  }
```

An optimization you might look into is to do the probability selection using ints instead of floats, might be slightly faster. Here is a short proof I did some time ago regarding that this works: [here](http://rafal.io/posts/assorted-notes.html#random-element-from-finite-stream) . I believe the algorithm is attributed to Knuth but can't remember exactly.